# Restrict default templates using Draw.io embed

Tags: draw.io

Is it possible to restrict the default templates used in draw.io? I can restrict the custom libraries accessible by passing in an array at the start, but there appears to be no such parameters that limit the initial templates.

[image: All the templates. :(]

I've went through [the documentation](https://desk.draw.io/support/home#) but still cannot find the option to modify. It's not a deal-breaker but I'd love to be able to reduce these templates dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

BR,